# Stochastic process: Number of states visited in $n < \infty$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am from Spain and I don't know the exact English term, so I will try to explain the definition.

In a discrete stochastic process, let:

- P be the transition matrix with all is states being recurrent, where $p_{ij}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $j$.
- $\tau_j$ be the first time we arrive at $j$
- $f^{(n)}_{ij}=P_i(\tau_j=n)$ be the probability to arrive the first time at $j$ from $i$ in the $n$ time
- $f_{ij}=P_i(\tau_j< \infty)$ be the probability to arrive to $j$ from $i$. In a recursive state $f_{ij}=1$

To calculate the number of times we visit the state $j$ starting from the state $i$ before the process stops $E_i[V_j]$ I use the following formula $E_i[V_j]=\frac{f_{ij}}{1-f_{jj}}$

In a recurrent matrix (a matrix where all its states comply with $f_{ij}=1$), how can I get $E_i[V_j]$? the number of times we visit $j$ starting from $i$ in $n$ times.

Comment: I edited your title, nothing can be equal to infinity since it is not a number...

Comment: I have made some spelling and grammatical corrections that hopefully make your post easier to understand (it's still not quite correct but I hesitate to change more in case I alter your meaning). Please check it still says what you intend.

Comment: Two questions. First, is the state space finite? Second, what is $V_j$? You're saying the number of times we visit state $j$ starting from $i$ before the process stops. When is the process defined to stop? Is it when it comes back to $i$?

Comment: The space state is finite, an the process stops when we do n iterations.

Lets see an example. Supouse that there are 3 states. {1, 2, 3}. $p_{1,1}=1/2, p_{1,2}=1/2, p_{2,1}=1/2, p_{2,3}=1/2, p_{3,2}=1/2,  p_{3,3}=1/2$. After 30 iterations, What is the average number of times we visit the state 2 starting from the sate 2?